# Disable anti-aliasing when exporting a png with canvas.toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas that I draw some shapes on using fabric.js. I then fill those shapes, and draw them on another canvas using context.drawImage() to export to a png using canvas.toDataURL().

I have turned off enableRetinaScaling and imageSmoothingEnabled for both the canvas I draw onto, and the canvas I export to a png.

My resulting png has different color pixels on the edge of shapes, and seems to be anti-aliased or blurred. Is there a way to disable this and have every pixel be the same color around the borders? I know this will result is a less smooth edge, and that's fine.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

const drawingCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvas, {
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  selection: false,
  enableRetinaScaling: false,
  imageSmoothingEnabled: false,
});

let polygon = new fabric.Polygon([
  {  x: 50,  y: 100 }, 
  {  x: 70,  y: 10 }, 
  {  x: 90,  y: 100 }, 
], {
  stroke: 'green',
  fill: 'green',
  selectable: false,
  perPixelTargetFind: true,
  hoverCursor: 'cursor'
});

drawingCanvas.add(polygon);
drawingCanvas.renderAll();

link = document.getElementById('download');
link.setAttribute("href", canvas.toDataURL());
link.setAttribute("download", "example.png");
```

```html
<body>
  <a id="download"><button>Download</button></a>
  <canvas id="canvas" style="border: solid red 1px" />
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.5/fabric.js"></script>
```

**A close up of the png, showing different pixel shades**
[image: A close up of the png, showing different pixel shades]

Comment: Are you using `encoderOptions` in your toDataURL? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: It would be great if you can create a minimal code snippet with one simple shape showing your issue

Comment: @HelderSepu - For the default pngs, encoder options seems to do nothing. It only says it effects alternative formats.

Comment: I'll try get some sample code up later.

Comment: Here's a codepen. If you download both the small and big png, when you zoom in on the shape, you can see the pixel color difference. I want all pixels to be the same shade of green, or be transparent.

https://codepen.io/carter485/pen/ajroNO?editors=1011

Comment: If you don't want to change the original image, I would draw it to an invisible canvas, set its `context.imageSmoothingQuality = "low"`, then use `toDataURL()`

Comment: @VictorStoddard - Tried this, and still see pixel color differences around the edges of the shape. Try out the codepen, and see if you can make all the pixels the same shade.

Comment: @carterw485 I saw your reply only after I posted mine. I tried your pen and it worked fine. I didn't know fabric had a tempCanvas feature. Great solution.

Comment: @VictorStoddard - I don't have a solution. I'm looking for a way to make all of the pixels around the edges in the png 1 color. Look at my third photo here. I need all of the partially shades pixels to either be the same green as the middle of the shape, or transparent.

Comment: @carterw485 Oh, I took a closer look. It looked like the anti-aliasing is gone but a few green border pixels are off color. I'll look into it.

Comment: I reduced your code and add it as a snippet

Comment: @carterw845 can you just ping me so i get a notificatio n and i find again this question later?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi - pinging you

Comment: i  answered down here

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by the algorithm used to draw lines in a canvas, and I don't think we have a way to change it, the only option is to draw everything yourself using a different algorithm like:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

And in your sample you are using fabric.js but this is happening also with the most basic form of line drawing as well, here is and example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = canvas.height = 50;
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false
ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5)
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 10);
ctx.lineTo(10, 10);
ctx.lineTo(30, 30);
ctx.lineTo(40, 10);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

link = document.getElementById('download');
link.setAttribute("href", canvas.toDataURL());
link.setAttribute("download", "example.png");
```

```html
<body>
  <a id="download"><button>Download</button></a><br>
  <canvas id="canvas" style="border: solid red 1px" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution.
You can't remove the aliasing from canvas, at least is not in the specs, and is not under your control.

But you can manipulate pixels after exporting them.

The ouput is:

[image]

But it won't work for overlapping shapes.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

const drawingCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvas, {
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  selection: false,
  enableRetinaScaling: false,
  imageSmoothingEnabled: false,
});

let polygon = new fabric.Polygon([
  {  x: 50,  y: 100 }, 
  {  x: 70,  y: 10 }, 
  {  x: 90,  y: 100 }, 
], {
  stroke: 'green',
  fill: 'green',
  selectable: false,
  perPixelTargetFind: true,
  hoverCursor: 'cursor'
});

drawingCanvas.add(polygon);
drawingCanvas.renderAll();

function myNewImage() {
  const _canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const pixels = drawingCanvas.lowerCanvasEl;
  _canvas.width = pixels.width;
  _canvas.height = pixels.height;
  const ctx = _canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(pixels, 0, 0);
  const data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, _canvas.width, _canvas.height);
  const pixelArray = data.data;
  for (let i = 3; i < pixelArray.length; i += 4) {
    if (pixelArray[i] < 128) {
      pixelArray[i] = 0;
    } else {
      pixelArray[i] = 255;
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
  return _canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}

link = document.getElementById('download');
link.setAttribute("href", myNewImage());
link.setAttribute("download", "example.png");
```

```html
<body>
  <a id="download"><button>Download</button></a>
  <canvas id="canvas" style="border: solid red 1px" />
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.5/fabric.js"></script>
```